Using XGBoost as a submodel for a hybrid ML/process-based model
I am trying to fit a Chapman-Richards growth curve:
$$
B = A*(1-e^{-kt})
$$
Where B is the biomass of a forest, A is the asymptote, k is the growth rate, and t is forest age. I expect the growth rate to be a function of multiple environmental predictors.
I have fit this curve using Nelder-Mead gradient descent with reasonable success. I considered k to be a linear combination of the environmental predictors. I understand that the linear combination is an oversimplification, and may explain the not-so-great predictive power. 
Using XGBoost to predict directly the biomass from all predictors (pure ML approach), the R squared values are much better... but it is useless to me since I ultimately need a growth equation to extrapolate beyond the range of the data.
While looking at alternatives to improve the fit of the curve, I came across hybrid models, and I would like to use XGBoost to estimate the k parameter of my process based model.
The only way I could think of implementing that in my case is:
1 - K-means to divide the dataframe into clusters with similar environmental conditions
2 - fit chapman-richards to each cluster using gradient descent/nelder mead
3 - use XGBoost to predict the k values (found in step 2) for each cluster from the \environmental predictors
4 - use the trained XGBoost model to make new k values for new data.
Is this the best way to work with a hybrid model in my case? Are there better approaches I may not have considered?
